# CPUpower sets the frequency by itself

Tags: cpu, cpufreq

Whenever I try to change the governor or CPU frequency with CPUpower, after 10-20 seconds it starts to go up again.Lets say I set the maximum CPU frequency to 1.5GHz it will go to 1.76GHz and then to the max CPU frequency which in my case is 2.2GHz.I have Dell laptop with Intel Pentium.